# Erro AndroidManifest.xml - É esperado um nome de um pseudo-atributo.

Tags: android, xml

Bom dia,
Quando vou executar a aplicação, aparece uma mensagem de erro no AndroidManifest.xml

"Error:Exception while parsing the supplied manifest file C:\Users\Weslley\AndroidStudioProjects\ProjectName\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml > É esperado um nome de um pseudo-atributo. "

Abaixo código AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher2"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.DashboardActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".activities.NoInternetConnectionActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".activities.UnavailableServiceActivity" />
</application>
```

Comment: acredito que voce tenho de por essa linha: `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` dentro da tag application, tenta ai

Comment: Coloquei e o erro ainda continua :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esse trecho:

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
```

está solto no código. Deveria estar dentro da TAG `<application>`, como os demais.

O manifest também deve começar com essa TAG:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

E todo o resto do seu código acima (do manifest) deve estar dentro dessas tags (e abaixo da TAG acima):

```
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="NOME DO PACKAGE">

... SEU CÓDIGO
</manifest>
```

Comment: Coloquei e o erro ainda continua :(

Comment: O erro não indica a linha?

Comment: Editei minha resposta

Comment: Consegui vê onde estava o erro. Nessa parte <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>, acidentalmente troquei version para mversion. Alterei e ficou tudo certo. Obrigado pela ajuda